# Simple way to see that $r=\frac{st}{s+t}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, rational-numbers

Consider the system of equations

$$ f(x)=g(x)=h(x) $$

where $f(x)= \exp\bigg(\frac{s}{\log x} \bigg) $ and $g(x)=\exp\bigg( \frac{t}{\log(1-x)} \bigg)$ and $h(x)=\exp\bigg(\frac{r}{\log x}+\frac{r}{\log (1-x)}\bigg)$. Here $s,t\in \Bbb N$ and $r\in \Bbb Q_+$ and $x\in (0,1),$ and where $r=\frac{st}{s+t}$.

> Is there a simple way to see that $r=\frac{st}{s+t}$?

I manipulated the equations but I still don't see why $r$ should be related to $s$ and $t$ like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\exp$ is injective, the equality $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)$ implies that $$\frac{s}{\log x} = \frac{t}{\log (1-x)} = r \left(\frac{1}{\log x} + \frac{1}{\log(1-x)}\right)$$ for all $x \in (0,1).$ The idea now is to pick a particular $x$. In this setting $x = 1/2$ seems natural due to the symmetry. Plugging $x=1/2$ in the last equation leads to $$\frac{s}{\log(1/2)} = \frac{t}{\log (1/2)} = \frac{2r}{\ln(1/2)}.$$ Hence $$s=t=2r.$$ From these equalities, you can easily deduce that $$\frac{st}{s+t} = \frac{(2r)(2r)}{2r+2r}=\frac{4r^2}{4r}=r.$$

Comment: This argument is incorrect. Verifying that the relation holds at a single $x$ value says nothing about whether it is true for all $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$. You might just as well conclude that $r=(s+t)/4$, but this is not true for all $x$.

Comment: It's the other way around. It is admitted from the beginning that the equality holds for all x.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify $f(x)=g(x)$ to
$$\frac{s}{\log x} = \frac{t}{\log (1-x)}$$
which leads to
$$\frac{\log (1-x)}{\log x} = \frac{t}{s}$$

Similarly you can simplify $f(x)=h(x)$ to:
$$\frac{s}{\log x} = r \left(\frac{1}{\log x} + \frac{1}{\log(1-x)}\right)\\ \frac{s-r}{\log x} = \frac{r}{\log(1-x)} \\ \frac{\log(1-x)}{\log x} = \frac{r}{s-r} $$

These two equations have the same left hand sides, so their right hand sides are equal too, giving:
$$ \frac{t}{s} = \frac{r}{s-r} $$
Solving for $r$ gives:
$$ t(s-r) = rs \\ st-rt=rs \\ st = r(s+t) \\ r=\frac{st}{s+t}$$